# Why am I getting a CORS error when attempting to fetch data from my Loopback server hosted on AWS despite having set the origin to "*"?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, express, cors, loopback

Why do I get a CORS error when attempting to fetch data from my loopback server hosted on AWS, despite having set the origin to "*"?

I am trying to fetch data from my remotely hosted loopback server to a simple html-page using the following code:

```
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'api-target': 'rest'
};
fetch("https://nightli-staging-server.link/public-guest-lists/1", {
  headers: headers
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    const widget = document.getElementById("widget");
    widget.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
  });
```

However, I receive the following CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://nightli-staging-server.link/public-guest-lists/1' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have set the origin to "*" in my index.ts file, which is used to start the loopback server. Here is the relevant part of the index.ts file:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'],
};
expressApp.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Why am I still encountering a CORS error? What else could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Posting relevant files from the remotely hosted loopback server (should it help):

index.ts:

```
import aws from 'aws-sdk';
import cors from 'cors';
import express, {NextFunction} from 'express';
import {graphqlHTTP} from 'express-graphql';
import {createServer as createServerHttp} from 'http';
import {createGraphQLSchema, Oas3} from 'openapi-to-graphql';
import qs from 'qs';
import {ApplicationConfig, NightliBackendApplication} from './application';

export * from './application';

export async function main(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
  const expressApp = express();
  let url = `${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT ?? 3000}`;

  const app = new NightliBackendApplication(options);
  await app.boot();
  await app.start();
  url = app.restServer.url!;
  console.log(`Server is running at ${url}`);
  console.log(`Connected to database ${process.env.DB_DATABASE}`);
  const oas = await app.restServer.getApiSpec();
  const graphResult = await createGraphQLSchema(oas as Oas3, {
    strict: false,
    viewer: false,
    singularNames: true,
    fillEmptyResponses: true,
    baseUrl: url,
    headers: {
      'X-Origin': 'GraphQL',
    },
    tokenJSONpath: '$.jwt',
  });
  const {schema} = graphResult;
  const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'],
    headers: ['Content-Type', 'api-target']
  };
  expressApp.use(cors(corsOptions));

  expressApp.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
  expressApp.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));
  // For AWS ALB health checks
  expressApp.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
  expressApp.use(
    '/graphql',
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises
    graphqlHTTP(request => ({
      schema,
      graphiql: true,
      context: {
        jwt: request.headers.authorization?.replace(/^Bearer /, ''),
      },
    })),
  );

  aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  });

  const server = createServerHttp(expressApp);
  const graphqlPort = process.env.GRAPHQL_PORT ?? 3001;
  server.listen(graphqlPort, () => {
    console.log(
      `GraphQL is running at http://${process.env.HOST}:${graphqlPort}/graphql`,
    );
  });

  return app;
}

if (require.main === module) {
  // Run the application
  const config: ApplicationConfig = {
    rest: {
      port: +(process.env.PORT ?? 3000),
      host: process.env.HOST,
      // The `gracePeriodForClose` provides a graceful close for http/https
      // servers with keep-alive clients. The default value is `Infinity`
      // (don't force-close). If you want to immediately destroy all sockets
      // upon stop, set its value to `0`.
      // See https://www.npmjs.com/package/stoppable
      gracePeriodForClose: 5000, // 5 seconds
      cors: {
        origin: '*',
        methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
        preflightContinue: true,
        credentials: true,
        allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, api-target',
        exposedHeaders: ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'],
            // Add a function to log when an OPTIONS request is received
        optionsSuccess: function(req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction) {
          const origin = req.headers.get('origin');
          console.log("in optionsSucces!")
          console.log("req", req)
          if (origin) {
            console.log('Received OPTIONS request from:', origin);
          } else {
            console.log('Received OPTIONS request without Origin header.');
          }
          next();
        }
      },
      openApiSpec: {
        // useful when used with OpenAPI-to-GraphQL to locate your application
        setServersFromRequest: true,
      },
      expressSettings: {
        'query parser': function (value: string, option: any) {
          return qs.parse(value, {
            arrayLimit: 800,
          });
        },
      },
    },
  };
  console.log("CORS config:", config.rest.cors);
  main(config).catch(err => {
    console.error('Cannot start the application.', err);
    process.exit(1);
  });
}
```

controller with endpoint being called on:

```
import {inject} from '@loopback/core';
import {
  Request,
  RestBindings,
  SchemaObject,
  get,
  param,
  post,
  requestBody,
  response
} from '@loopback/rest';
import {ServerResponse} from 'http';
import {EventItemServiceBindings, GuestListServiceBindings} from '../keys';
import {CreatePublicGuestlist, GetPublicGuestListSchema, messageSchemaResponse} from '../schemas';
import {IEventItemService, IGuestListService} from '../services';
import {PublicGuestListPayload, PublicGuestListType} from '../types';


export class PublicGuestListController {
  constructor(
    @inject(GuestListServiceBindings.GUEST_LIST_SERVICE)
    public guestListService: IGuestListService,
    @inject(EventItemServiceBindings.EVENT_ITEM_SERVICE)
    public eventItemService: IEventItemService,
  ) { }

  @post('/public-guest-lists/{clubId}')
  @response(200, {
    description: 'Create public guest and add to public guest list',
    content: {'application/json': {schema: messageSchemaResponse}},
  })
  async createPublicGuestList(
    @param.path.number('clubId') clubId: number,
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: CreatePublicGuestlist as SchemaObject,
        },
      },
    })
    payload: PublicGuestListPayload,
    @inject(RestBindings.Http.REQUEST)
    request: Request,
    @inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) response: ServerResponse,
  ): Promise<{message: string}> {
    await this.guestListService.addToPublicGuestList(clubId, payload);

    // Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to allow all connections
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    return {message: 'Request sent'};
  }

  @get('/public-guest-lists/{clubId}')
  @response(200, {
    description: 'Get public guest lists (event_items) for club',
    content: {'application/json': {schema: GetPublicGuestListSchema}},
  })
  async getPublicGuestLists(
    @param.path.number('clubId') clubId: number,
    @inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) response: ServerResponse,
  ): Promise<PublicGuestListType[]> {
    const publicGuestLists = await this.eventItemService.getPublicEventItemsByClub(clubId);

    // Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to allow all connections
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    return publicGuestLists;
  }


}
```

sequence.ts file:

```
import {MiddlewareSequence} from '@loopback/rest';

export class MySequence extends MiddlewareSequence {}
```

application.ts file:

```
import {AuthenticationComponent} from '@loopback/authentication';
import {
  AuthorizationBindings,
  AuthorizationComponent,
  AuthorizationDecision,
} from '@loopback/authorization';
import {BootMixin} from '@loopback/boot';
import {ApplicationConfig} from '@loopback/core';
import {CronComponent} from '@loopback/cron';
import {RepositoryMixin} from '@loopback/repository';
import {RestApplication} from '@loopback/rest';
import {
  RestExplorerBindings,
  RestExplorerComponent,
} from '@loopback/rest-explorer';
import {ServiceMixin} from '@loopback/service-proxy';
import path from 'path';
import {BindingComponent} from './bindings';
import {PostgresqlDataSource} from './datasources';
import {UserServiceBindings} from './keys';
import {MySequence} from './sequence';

export {ApplicationConfig};

export class NightliBackendApplication extends BootMixin(
  ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication)),
) {
  constructor(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
    super(options);

    // Set up the custom sequence
    this.sequence(MySequence);

    // Set up default home page
    this.static('/', path.join(__dirname, '../public'));

    // Customize @loopback/rest-explorer configuration here
    this.configure(RestExplorerBindings.COMPONENT).to({
      path: '/explorer',
    });
    this.component(RestExplorerComponent);
    // Mount authentication system
    this.component(AuthenticationComponent);
    // Mount authorization system
    this.configure(AuthorizationBindings.COMPONENT).to({
      precedence: AuthorizationDecision.DENY,
      defaultDecision: AuthorizationDecision.DENY,
    });
    this.component(AuthorizationComponent);
    // Mount jwt component
    this.component(BindingComponent);

    //  Cron job component
    this.component(CronComponent);

    // Bind datasource
    this.dataSource(PostgresqlDataSource, UserServiceBindings.DATASOURCE_NAME);
    this.projectRoot = __dirname;

    // logger
    // const fileTransport: DailyRotateFile = new DailyRotateFile({
    //   level: 'error',
    //   filename: 'logs/application-%DATE%.log',
    //   datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    //   format: combine(label({label: 'Error log!'}), timestamp(), errorFormat),
    //   zippedArchive: true,
    //   maxSize: '20m',
    //   maxFiles: '14d',
    // });

    // this.bind('logging.winston.transports.file')
    //   .to(fileTransport)
    //   .apply(extensionFor(WINSTON_TRANSPORT));

    // this.configure(LoggingBindings.COMPONENT).to({
    //   enableFluent: false,
    //   enableHttpAccessLog: true,
    // });

    // this.component(LoggingComponent);

    // Customize @loopback/boot Booter Conventions here
    this.bootOptions = {
      controllers: {
        // Customize ControllerBooter Conventions here
        dirs: ['controllers'],
        extensions: ['.controller.js'],
        nested: true,
      },
    };
  }
}
```

I confirmed that the endpoint is functioning correctly by adding a "api-target:rest" header to the fetch request in my browser. This overrode the preflight request headers and bypassed CORS restrictions, allowing the expected response body to be received successfully.

Update:

When hosting the client-side on a AWS S3 bucket I instead get this CORS error:

"Acess to fetch at 'https://nightli-staging-server.link/public-guest-lists/1' from origin 'https://nightli-widget.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

I have also now included console.logs in the index.ts file here

```
optionsSuccess: function(req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction) {
      const origin = req.headers.get('origin');
      console.log("in optionsSucces!")
      console.log("req", req)
      if (origin) {
        console.log('Received OPTIONS request from:', origin);
      } else {
        console.log('Received OPTIONS request without Origin header.');
      }
      next();
    }
  }
```

Without any logs showing in console.

Comment: Because you're including custom headers `Content-Type` and `api-target` in your request, the server's CORS configuration must explicitly allow those request headers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added 

    headers: ['Content-Type', 'api-target']

to the corsOptions in the index.ts file. 

Unfortunately, the same issue persists

Comment: What AWS service is being used?

Comment: Sending a docker image of the server to ECR and then hosting it through ECS

Comment: I'm confused to as why you passing `expressApp` inside of `createServerHttp()`

Instead you could call `expressApp.listen(3000, () => {console.log('Server is up')})`